# Perl array - trying to parse quotes in proper array elements

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I have been struggling with this for a while in a Perl script I have. Probably a slam dunk for you Perl experts, and probably should be easier, but I can't quite crack the nut on this. I might be needing to split this, not sure.

My array code as is follows.

```
while ( my $row = $query_handle->fetchrow_hashref('NAME_lc') ){  
    push @query_output, $row; 
    push (@{portfo->{label}},$row->{data},$row->{label}); 
}
```

And then my print of the array is as follows:

```
    print "array here--";
print "[";
foreach (@{portfo->{label}}) {
    #(@{portfo->{label}},$row->{data});
    print "\{\"data\":";
    print "".$_.",";
    print "\"label\":";
    print "\"".$row[1]."\"\},";
}
print "]";
print "\n";
```

And then my output looks like this:

```
[{"data":2943,"label":""},{"data":CDI3,"label":""}, 
{"data":1,"label":""},{"data":COS-COS2,"label":""}, 
{"data":1087,"label":""},{"data":COS1,"label":""},
{"data":5183,"label":""},{"data":COS2,"label":""},
{"data":2731,"label":""},{"data":CULB,"label":""},{"data":1,"label":""},
{"data":EQUIT,"label":""},{"data":4474,"label":""},
{"data":Network,"label":""},]
```

I am trying to make the apha-num string array items like CDI3, COS1, COS2, etc in quotes, in the label part. Somehow I'm getting it separated. Meanwhile, I do want the numeric values left with the "data" name pair.

```
[{"data":2943,"label":""},{"data":"CDI3","label":""}, 
{"data":1,"label":""},{"data":"COS-COS2","label":""}, 
{"data":1087,"label":""},{"data":"COS1","label":""},
{"data":5183,"label":""},{"data":"COS2","label":""},
{"data":2731,"label":""},{"data":"CULB","label":""},{"data":1,"label":""},
{"data":"EQUIT","label":""},{"data":4474,"label":""},
{"data":"Network","label":""}]
```

I'm sure it's a simpler fix that I'm making it but so far no luck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to build a JSON string, use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module (or [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS)).

Comment: Also, you're escaping too much in your strings. `print "\"".$row[1]."\"\},";` is better written `print "\"".$row[1]."\"},";` is better written `print "\"$row[1]\"},";` is better written `print qq("$row[1]"},);`

Comment: Also, this `print "".$_.",";` is just `print "$_,"`.  The four prints in the loop can feasibly be written as one, specially using [qq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) as in ThisSuitIsBlackNot comment.

Comment: So `print qq( {"data":$_,"label":"$row[1]"}, );`. To me this is clearer than when split up.

Comment: This doesn't quite do it....my output is still --

        array here--[{"data":2943,"label":""},{"data":CDI3,"label":""}, 
        {"data":1,"label":""},{"data":COS-COS2,"label":""}, 
        {"data":1087,"label":""},{"data":COS1,"label":""},
        {"data":5183,"label":""},{"data":COS2,"label":""},
{"data":2731,"label":""},{"data":CULB,"label":""},{"data":1,"label":""},
{"data":EQUIT,"label":""},{"data":4474,"label":""},
{"data":Network,"label":""},]    labels still not in quotes and associated with data

Comment: I probably didn't make it completely clear. I am pulling in a JSON string. What I am specifically trying to do in that JSON string is escape the quotes around the number values (only) returned.

Comment: I don't see quotes around any of the numbers in that JSON string. Also, `"data":CDI3` is wrong, `CDI3` is a string so it needs to be quoted: `"data":"CDI3"`. Please explain why you think you need to escape quotes and where this broken JSON is coming from. What are you trying to do, in a broader sense?

Comment: ^^^ - correct, but the other label strings do not have quotes in this instance, and they actually need them. i.e. the ones showing {"data":1087,"label":""},{"data":COS1,"label":""}, the COS1 string should be in quotes, and it should go next to the label key, which is somehow rendering a null value, rather than the label value.
A raw JSON string has this - [{"data":"2829","label":"CDI3"},{"data":"1","label":"COS-COS2"},{"data":"1070","label":"COS1"},{"data":"5090","label":"COS2"},{"data":"2817","label":"CULB"},{"data":"1","label":"EQUIT"},{"data":"4443","label":"Network"}]-nums in quotes here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use JSON::XS qw( encode_json );

my @data;
while ( my $row = $query_handle->fetchrow_hashref('NAME_lc') ) {  
   # If $row->{data} is a number,
   # make sure it's stored as a number
   # so that it gets serialized as a number.
   $row->{data} += 0 if $row->{data} =~ /^\d+\z/;

   push @data, $row;
}

print(encode_json(\@data));
```

Or

```
my $data = $query_handle->fetchall_arrayref({ data => 1, label => 1 });
for my $row (@$data) {
   $row->{data} += 0 if $row->{data} =~ /^\d+\z/;
}

print(encode_json($data));
```

Or if you ensure the fields names are returned as lowercase<sup>[1]</sup>,

```
my $data = $query_handle->fetchall_arrayref({});
for my $row (@$data) {
   $row->{data} += 0 if $row->{data} =~ /^\d+\z/;
}

print(encode_json($data));
```

---

1. This can be done using `$dbh->{FetchHashKeyName} = 'NAME_lc';` or `` AS `label` ``.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the above, and I'm still getting a regular JSON string with all the array items returned in quotes. I'm trying to simply parse the quotes around the data array items being returned. Thanks!

Comment: No idea what ate are talking about. 1) you specifically asked to place the elements in quotes, so why are you complaining about it now? 2) There's nothing related to parsing in your question.

Comment: no idea what I'm talking about? I'm talking about trying to PARSE the quotes around the data item in the array? I.e. instead of  [{"data":"2943",... like above I'm trying to return it as [{"data":2943,... Sorry, I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: Ah, my confusion is from your misuse of "parsing". Parsing is to take a string, turn it into tokens, and assign meaning to those tokens. You want the opposite. You're trying to *serialize*. Specifically, the issue is that you want the numbers in `data` to be serialized as JSON numbers. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: Apologies. I'm used to parsing meaning strip out, but I'm probably (incorrectly) applying the term here to Perl when it shouldn't be. But yes! Thank you much! I'll check it out!

Comment: No, that's not right either. There's no quotes in your data to strip out (remove).

Comment: HOLY SMOKES! That did it ikegami. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, one little thing I noticed. It's skipping the first record for some reason. Like from above, [{"data":2943,"label":"CDI3"} is getting skipped, but all others coming in fine. Trying to troubleshoot that one.

Comment: Nope, [not so](https://pastebin.com/FZTC7LZH). Perhaps you have a fetch outside of the loop?

Comment: Thanks, with your pastebin help I was able to get it resolved! Many thanks!